# javascript 'this' alerts undifned with in function

Tags: javascript, function

I have an issue with 'this' operator.

**Q:**

```
function xyz(){
 var b=10;
 alert(this.b); //value is undefined.
}
```

Here I know I will get alert as `undefined`. but I don't know why value is undefined.

Can any one help me.

Comment: The value is undefined because `this.b` does not exist. Why would it?

Comment: Try addig b as a parametr and removig the "var" keyword function xyz(b){}

Comment: `this` refers to `window` which is a global object, on which no `b` variable is defined..If you want to get alert do only `b=10`..

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the context the function is running with.

`b` is not part of that context.

If you want to add it there:

```
function xyz(){
 this.b = 10;
 alert(this.b); //value is 10.
}
```

Comment: Actually we don't even know `this` refers to `window` because we don't see the call site. The questioner could have issued `new xyz()` or `xyz.call(something)`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use the this property for your example.
You are asigning b as a variable within your function, so it is within the scope of that function. So you just need to do the following

```
function xyz(){
 var b=10;
 alert(b); //value is undefined.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because `b` is a local variable, that is accessible as `b` (not `this.b`). `This` in this context reference to the `window`, whose properties are global variables.

Answer (score 0):

The function in this case is "this", the function does not have the property 'b'. If you have a object somewhere else in your code, point it towards that object.

```
var obj = {
    b = 5
}

function xyz(){
     obj.b = 10;
     alert(obj.b)
}
```